# How to add multiple Jenkins jobs as a build parameters in single Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

->I have around 20 jobs which needs to be deployed parallel

I want to trigger these 20 jobs from single jenkins job.

I need to use those 20 jobs as build parameters in single jenkins job so i can choose which job to deploy.
Can someone help me with this requirement if there is any plugin or workaround?

I tried below options:

Active choices plugin and build flow plugin are not compatible with the current jenkins version 1.642 which i am using.
Multijob project can only deploy all jobs at once parallel but doesn't give any option/condition to run particular job.

Currently i am working on multijob phase project jenkins 
I am trying to use some conditions in Multijob phase project but jobs not  triggered as expected, If someone knows using conditions in multijob phase please lemme know

Thank you